# Remove symlink on Msys

Tags: symlink, msys

I used msys to create a symlink. Now I wish to remove it, but here's what I get:

```
$ ln -s /mypath mylink
$ rm mylink
rm: cannot remove directory `mylink': Is a directory
```

What's the proper way to remove a symlink on msys?

Comment: Note that MSYS doesn't actually create symlinks, but outright copies. Hence the need for `rm -r`.

Comment: That is disappointing, but it makes sense. I was (wrongly) surprised to find that symlinks could exist on a Windows system.

Comment: Fwiw, Cygwin supports symlinks properly, but Cygwin symlinks are only handled correctly by Cygwin programs. Also, Windows >=Vista actually does support symlinks, but by default only administrators are allowed to create them (e.g. using cmd.exe's `mklink` builtin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symlinks on MSys2 aren't real symlinks but copies. So you can actually use `rm`:

```
rm
    -r, -R, --recursive   remove directories and their contents recursively
```

Example:

```
rm -r mylink
```